# Formatting in the numpy matrix using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

[image: .dump]

Each **.dump** file will have similar formats as above picture. 
I have read the links that were suggested by the stackoverflow. I have stuck with the problem in numpy matrix where my format is totally different that was expected. I need a np.matrix of 4x4 size 4x1 size matrices. The values inside the matrix are certain float values.

```
#%%
def q_rot_trans(a,b,c,d,x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z2):
    '''Calculates the Rotation Matrix from Quaternion
    a is the real part
    b, c, d are the complex elements'''

    'defining Rotation vector'

    R11 = (a**2+b**2-c**2-d**2)
    R12 = 2.0*(b*c-a*d)
    R13 = 2.0*(b*d+a*c)

    R21 = 2.0*(b*c+a*d)
    R22 = a**2-b**2+c**2-d**2
    R23 = 2.0*(c*d-a*b)

    R31 = 2.0*(b*d-a*c)
    R32 = 2.0*(c*d+a*b)
    R33 = a**2-b**2-c**2+d**2

    'defining Translation vector'

    T11 = 1
    T12 = 0
    T13 = 0
    T14 = 0

    delta_x = x2 - x1
    delta_y = y2 - y1
    delta_z = z2 - z1

    T21 = delta_x
    T31 = delta_y
    T41 = delta_z

    'defining point vector'
    v11 = 1
    v12 = x1
    v13 = y1
    v14 = z1
    old_vector = np.matrix([[v11], [v12], [v13], [v14]])

    rot_trans = np.matrix([[T11, T12, T13, T14], [T21, R11, R12, R13], [T31, R21, R22, R23], [T41, R31, R32, R33]])

    'Finding new vector after transformation and rotation'
#    new_vector = np.matmul(rot_trans,old_vector).shape
    print(v11,v12,v13,v14,T11,T12,T13,T14,T21)
#    print('Rotation and Transformation matrix is: \n',rot_trans)
#    print('old vector is: \n', old_vector)
#    print('Transformed vector: ', new_vector)
    return 
#%%
i = pd.read_excel('paketone28000.dump.xlsx')  ##to read the excel file format

x1 = i['x']##import centre of mass from excel file format
y1 = i['y']
z1 = i['z']

q1 = i['q1'] ##attaining quaternons from excel file format. (comma(,) transformed series to tuple)
q2 = i['q2']
q3 = i['q3']
q4 = i['q4']
#%%

j = pd.read_excel('paketone32000.dump.xlsx')  ##to read the excel file format

x2 = j['x']##import centre of mass from excel file format
y2 = j['y']
z2 = j['z']
#%%

#print ('x1: ',x1, 'y1: ',y1, 'z1: ',z1, 'q1: ',q1, 'q2: ',q2, 'q3: ',q3, 'q4: ',q4, 'x2: ',x2,  'y2: ', y2, 'z2: ',z2)

#
q_rot_trans(q1,q2,q3,q4,x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z2 )
```

**I am obtaining results as follows:**

```
Rotation and Transformation matrix is: 
 [[1 0 0 0]
 [0    0.00001
Name: x, dtype: float64 -15.191110999999998 15.477 41.7978]
 [0    0.000058
Name: y, dtype: float64 44.516999999999996
  3.0911109999999997 15.034799999999997]
 [0   -0.006693
Name: z, dtype: float64 2.197800000000001 44.3652
  -15.628889000000003]]
old vector is: 
 [[1]
 [0    2.10005
Name: x, dtype: float64]
 [0   -0.101145
Name: y, dtype: float64]
 [0    0.739066
Name: z, dtype: float64]]
```

But the expected result should be in in matrix format of sizes 4x4 and 4x1 respectively of which these two matrices are to be multiplied and have to obtain a 4x1 size matrix.

Comment: Don't use np.matrix  it can only be 2d

Comment: But this worked well when i have used for 3x3 matrix size

Comment: I need some more suggestions to improve my code.

Comment: What are these `x1`, `y1` etc objects.  I don't know what it is that's displaying as `Name: x, dtype: float64`.  Your code is incomplete, so we can't reproduce it or make suggestions on improvement.

Comment: ok, now i have added full code where you can have a look

Comment: I have recently added picture of how a dump file of mine in dataframe will look like

Comment: So `x1`  is a pandas `Series`.  No wonder the display looks odd. You are making `np.matrix` with object dtype - it contains a mix of numbers and `Series`.  In Python formatting is determined by the objects that are being displayed.  To get a desired format, you have start with the right kind of object.  I suspect you want an array of floats, not an array of mixed objects.  Focus on getting the desired value(s) from the `i` and `j` DataFrames.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Let me know for clear view to understand.

Comment: I have run the some of the same format series one month back but now its showing error  even the code is same.

Comment: Even my excel file has values in float. Like 1.222245, 2.3422...... but i don’t have clue why i am obtaining in series format. Can you help me what can be done further to obtain perfect matrix format?

Comment: If `i` is a DataFrame` then `i['x']` is a Pandas `Series`.  Look at the `type` of `x1`.  But try this: `np.array([[0], x1, y1])`.  Pay attention to the number of brackets.  Or `np.array([ 0, x1[0], y1[0]])`.

Comment: Ok i will try and let you know. But why are you keeping [0] in initial column?

Comment: we have to match dimensions with the Series.

Comment: Thanks for that but it haven't worked. Let me know as my dataframe is in such a way as in picture. I want to assign the value to another variable as in program. so, that i can avoid series formation. how can i proceed?

Comment: I have solved from series to float using ``x1 = i.iloc[0,0]`` this statement.